# data is not inserted into mysql database but code runs without error

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to insert form data into mysql database but it is not inserted into table and there is no error!

Here is my code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $shop = $_POST['shopname'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO registration (shop_name,name,username,email,password,repassword,phone) VALUES  ('$shop','$name''$user','$email','$password','$repassword','$phone')";
  if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Signup Sucessfull";
  } else {
    echo mysqli_error();
  }
}
?>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: So, *"Signup Sucessfull"* message coming?

Comment: An aside from your issue, but it does not make sense to store password and repeated password in the database. Compare in your PHP, fail if they don't match, and only store it once if they match. Also, don't store password in plain text, hash them using the [password API](http://php.net/password), and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to remove your current risk of SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you forgot to mention a comma after the name.

```
'$name''$user'   // Missing comma in between
```

Also, it should be mysqli_error($con) instead of mysqli_error()

Try some debugging:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO registration (shop_name,name,username,email,password,repassword,phone) VALUES  ('".$shop."','".$name."', '".$user."','".$email."','".$password."','".$repassword."','".$phone."')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: i put comma between both variables but it didn't solve my problem its still running without any error but not saved to database

Answer (score 0):

> You seems to miss "," between the insert values. This code will work fine.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $shop = $_POST['shopname'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO registration (shop_name,name,username,email,password,repassword,phone) VALUES  ('".$shop."','".$name."','".$user."','".$email."','".$password."','".$repassword."','".$phone."')";
  if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Signup Sucessfull";
  } else {
    die(mysqli_error($con));
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, As already **[@ObjectManipulator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5113881/object-manipulator)** pointed your silly mistake
>   near `'$name''$user'`.

I will strongly recommend you to use [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1875) to avoid SQL Injection.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO registration (shop_name,name,username,email,password,repassword,phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssss',$_POST['shopname'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['repassword'],$_POST['phone']);

  if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Signup Sucessfull";
  } else {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
  }
}
?>
```

> And, as **[@JonStirling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jon-stirling)** suggested not to store password in plain text
>   and use any [Password API](http://php.net/password) to encrypt password.

There are many ways to encrypt your password. Use anyone of them. Right now, I illustrated with [md5()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php).

And, Why to store `password` and `repassword` in database table. While storing user data into database table, check there itself if password & repassword matches or not.

Just a suggestion. It's upto you to choose.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['repassword']) && ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['repassword'])){
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO registration (shop_name,name,username,email,password,phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss',$_POST['shopname'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['username'],$_POST['email'],md5($_POST['password']),$_POST['phone']);

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
      echo "Signup Sucessfull";
    } else {
      echo mysqli_error();
    }
  } else {
    echo "Password must match.";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `md5` is **not recommended** for password encryption. This hash has been repeatedly compromised and is too fast. Use instead PHP `password_hash`

Comment: i am new in php i just want to store data into database and yes i will store encrypted password instead of plain text

Comment: After using this code also not inserted into database @Ashutosh?

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

Problem solved. You forgot the connection details `$con` for your MySQL error output. This will now correctly output your MySQL Syntax mistakes from your query.

---

### Other Notes:

- Use Prepared statements for MySQLi ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1875))
- Use a proper Password hashing algorithm such as [`Password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Do not use MD5 (it's too fast and has too many collisions) and *NEVER* store passwords as plaintext.
- Use the various [`filter_Var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) on your POSTed variables to clean them and make sure you catch any invalid data (such as improper email addresses)

Answer (score 0):

Put comma in your sql query as below

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO registration (shop_name,name,username,email,password,repassword,phone)VALUES  
('$shop','$name','$user','$email','$password','$repassword','$phone')";
```